# Add public key to ec2 instance from AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

There's a lot of buttons on the AWS console. Is it possible to add a public key to an ec2 instance strictly using the EC2 dashboard?

I'm not on the machine that contains the original keypair associated with the instance, so I don't have ssh access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Not possible. The key is added when you launch. Any new public key has to be associated with a new user, for that you have to be logged into that instance.

If you lose the original key(pair) you are out of luck. There is a way to attach your root partition to some other instance, fix the public key and reattach the partition to your instance. Search Stack Overflow for that solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Connecting to your Linux instance if you lose your private key

I add the link to the docs, to extend helloV answer.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/replacing-lost-key-pair.html

### Edit

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#replacing-lost-key-pair